# C++: how to start reading from certain lines in a txt file?

Tags: c++, loops

C++ beginner project, help to get the program start reading from certain lines.

We have an input txt file that contains some customer information: name, address, two numbers, with each piece taking one line. We need to read the file, print out the name, address, do some calculation with the number and send all three outputs to an output file.

The txt file contains 3 cases (9 lines).

I can read one case, but am having trouble writing a loop that can go through three cases. How can I tell c++ that it needs to start at the beginning of the fourth line and do the same iteration as it has done with the first case? Below is what I did with the first case.

```
    getline(infile, customerName);
    getline(infile, customerAddress);
    infile >> sqFeetOfTile >> costPerSqFt;
```

Comment: It's usually easiest to just call `std::getline` the required number of times and ignore the string it reads. You can use `ignore`, but it's more work (usually for little or no benefit).

Comment: There's no way to just jump straight to the start of an arbitrary line unless all the lines are exactly the same length. You need to read and skip over the lines you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't actually want to *start* reading at the fourth line (skipping three lines) but that you want to read three lines, and then continue on the fourth.

In that case your only problem is that reading the numbers doesn't consume the newline that follows them, so when you `getline` after that, the lone newline becomes the first "line", and soon after that you run into an error when you attempt to read the address into `sqFeetOfTile`.

The best way to do this is to always read complete lines.
If a line contains multiple parts, turn it into a `std::istringstream` and read the parts from that.
This method doesn't leave any stray newlines in  the stream, and you can just continue from where the first record left off.

Like this:

```
void processOneCustomer(std::istream& infile)
{
    std::string customerName;
    std::getline(infile, customerName);
    std::string customerAddress;
    std::getline(infile, customerAddress);
    std::string numbers;
    std::getline(infile, numbers);
    std::istringstream numberstream(numbers);
    float sqFeetOfTile = 0;
    int costPerSqFeet = 0;
    numbers >> sqFeetOfTile >> costPerSqFt;
    // Output customer data
    // Do calculations
}

// ...

while (inFile)
{
    processOneCustomer(inFile);
}
```

(Of course, real code should probably check for errors and stuff like that.)

If you do want to skip the first three lines, just call `std::getline` three times.